# Firestore Database structure for user content

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I can not find a example for a user structure for the Firestore database.

I assumed it should look something like that:

```
{
  users: {
    <authkey>: {
      userdata: {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the Realtimedatabase it would have worked if I just created a reference to `users/[authkey]/userdata` and set a value in there. The Databasestructure gets created automaticly. If I do the same in Firestore I can see the values in die Firebase console, but the values are marked as not existing and not queryable.

So do I have to create the document, collection structure myself when a User registers?
And what is the  best practice for creating a user database?

EDIT:

```
fs.doc('users/' + this.as.user.uid)
  .collection('accounts')
  .add({name: 'name'});
```

[The added Document ist grey and italic, in the bottom right is the error notice. Its in german, but it means something like: The document does not exist. You an not query or receive snapshots from the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4TyV.png)

Comment: The same basic approach should work, so likely something went wrong in your specific implementation. Please share the [minimum code that is needed to reproduce your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I can query the data, but in the firebase console there the data ist grey und there is a comment: the document does not exist, it will not be displayed in querys and snapshots.

Comment: The code you shared does not create a document for the user. It just creates the subcollection, which you can access through the console. While its uncommon to not have the document in this scenario, it is technically allowed and seems to work fine.

Comment: Ok, so i should always create a new Document, right?

Comment: There is no technical requirement to create a new document. That depends on your use-case.

Comment: What is the disadvantage of not creating a document?